# HP printer gets progressively less responsive through the day

Tags: windows, printer

we have a HP LaserJet 400 MFP M425dn which is experiencing some issues.
The printer works fine for a while, but eventually starts to be very laggy and slow, the touch screen becomes less responsive, and buttons pressed on the screen take 5-10 seconds to light up blue to indicate they've been pressed. Scans to a network drive take several minutes to go through, and occasionally fail.

When the printer starts to slow down, the web management console also gets very slow, taking several seconds to go to a new page or apply new settings.

After this starts happening, a reboot of the printer will get it working well again for a couple more hours, then it starts to happen again.

The only thing I've noticed on the troubleshooting side of things, is that while the printer is unresponsive, under the network performance tab I can see that transmit collisions and transmit late collisions will increase, I saw transmit collisions go from 25 to over 100 in the space of a few minutes:

[image]

The firmware was just updated (issue was present before and after update). The printer is connected through Ethernet, and not USB. Not sure what could be causing this, it almost seems like a memory leak though. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a Technical support request — Questions asking about troubleshooting hardware or technical support for hardware are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).